# Помогите, пожалуйста создать поддомены на Apache

Tags: php, yii2, apache, http, apache2

Вопрос такой есть Url:
site.loc/store/store_name
Нужно что бы при переходе на этот Url, отображалось store_name.site.loc/store, т.е. название магазина сделать поддоменом
Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В hosts нужно прописать subdomain. Думаю это должно помочь
https://www.binarytides.com/create-localhost-sub-domains-apache-ubuntu/
https://askubuntu.com/questions/463618/setting-up-subdomain-on-ubuntu-server